# Конструктор и оператор копирования

Tags: конструктор, c++

У меня есть класс в нем конструктор и оператор описанные вот так:

```
MyClass(const MyClass & c)
operator=(const MyClass & c);
```

В этом случаи я могу создать экземпляр вот так:

```
MyClass c;
```

Если я сделаю его вот так:

```
MyClass * с = new MyClass()
```

То оператор и конструктор описанные перед этим не вызовутся, т.к & и *.

А вот если я напишу 2 варианта операторов и конструкторов для ссылочки и указателя, то тогда оно должны сработать? И будет ли так правильно с точки зрения программирования и C++?

Например:

```
MyClass(const MyClass & c);
MyClass(const MyClass * c);
operator=(const MyClass & c);
operator=(const MyClass * c);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете так написать, но это не сработает. Потому что тип аргумента есть тип правой части оператора. `a = b` интерпретируется компилятором (приблизительно, полные детали очень обширны и [скучны](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment)) как `typeof(a).operator=(b)`.

Когда вы пишете

```
MyClass * с = new MyClass();
```

вы вызываете `operator=` у типа `MyClass*`, а не `MyClass`. А ваша перегрузка лишь для типа `MyClass`.

Comment: @VladD я и написал внизу 2 варианта операторов и конструкторов.
Тоесть если я опишу класс, как написал внизу, то в случаи:
MyClass c;
вызовется для &, а если через выделения памяти, то оператор (конструктор) с *? Я правильно вас понял?

Comment: @VladD вообще вопрос состоит в том: нужно ли так делать? Мой класс, требует того, чтобы не было побитового копирования и Экземпляр класса должен создаваться 2-мя путями.

Comment: @andrei1610: ваши перегруженные конструкторы вовсе не вызываются, т. к. объект создаётся лишь один раз и с конструктором без параметров.

Для `MyClass c;` вызывается лишь конструктор `MyClass` без аргументов. Для `MyClass* c = new MyClass();` вызывается (1) конструктор `MyClass()` (без аргументов), (2) оператор присваивания в `MyClass*`. Поскольку этот оператор невозможно перегрузить (класс `MyClass*` не доступен), вызывается встроенный в язык оператор копирования указателей.

Comment: @andrei1610: Если у вашего класса нетривиальный layout, побитового копирования и не будет. Если конструктор, создаваемый по умолчанию вас не устраивает (например, в вашем классе есть указатели), вам нужно определить copy constructor и operator=.

При вызове `MyClass * с = new MyClass();` копирования объекта не происходит, копируется лишь указатель на него.